# Moving OneNote document from Office 365 to OneDrive

Tags: onenote

Here is my scenario.

I am trying to parse documents in OneDrive for Business from Office 365 Document Library and display in a web app. The OneNote API currently does not work with  OneDrive for Business for Office 365.

So I am trying to download the files locally and then upload to OneDrive for Personal so that I can use OneNote API to get sections and pages. However, when I upload the files to Personal OneDrive the files are not treated as a OneNote Drive Web compatible file, .i.e I can't edit the files on web instead it downloads the files.

Only way I can get it done is Open the locally downloaded file in OneNote Client app and manually click "File->Share" it to Personal OneNote Drive before I can work with OneNote API. Is there a way to automate the process of Sharing the local files to OneNote Personal drive?

Thanks.